# Get value from link and use it for title attribute

Tags: php, css, drupal

How do i get the value from a link
and use it for the title attribute
from:

```
<a href="#">Test</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="#" title="Test"></a>
```

I use drupal as CMS

I use the css content property to display the title.
It would b so much easier if there was a value property for content.

Thanks

This is my navigation code:

```
<nav id="main_menu">


            <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix')))); ?>
          </nav><!-- /#main_menu -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $value = $('a').text();
    $('a').attr('title', $value);
});
```

EDIT :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('a').each(function() {
    $value = $(this).text();
    $(this).attr('title', $value);
 }) 
});
```

Comment: It works like i want but it take all the a's values and paste it in to each a

Answer (score 2):

If the `<a>` element had an ID you could do:

```
value = document.getElementById("ahrefid").innerHTML;
```

Comment: all the menu items need to have their value as title.
Can you tell me how to implement it to a drupal main menu?

Comment: for assigning that value to the title just do document.getElementById("ahrefid").setAttribute("Title", value);
i don't know about drupal specifics..

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<a id="anchorId" href="#">Test</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var anchorVal = document.getElementById("anchorId").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("anchorId").setAttribute("title", anchorVal)
```

**[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vReJx/)**